# Why I have syntax error in IDE after adding a gradle project to another repo even when the building works?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a kotlin multiplatform project A setup for iOS and Android, it works well. It has a `common` module for sharing business logic, and `platform-android` and `platform-ios` module for implementing the platform API.

After I adding the `common` and `platform-android` module from project A to another Android project B, the Android Studio IDE reports tons of syntax error, but the codes build and run from Android studio without a problem.

The syntax looks like the `kotlin-stdlib` is not there while it's indeed in the `build.gradle`, otherwise it won't build.

For instance:

`val filterMap = mutableMapOf<String, MenuFilter>()`

Android studio will say `Unresolved reference: mutableMapOf`

Some facts:

- `common` module has the problem
- no problem for `platform-android`.
- and of course, no problem when I use IDEA to edit project A

**my `build.gradle` for `common` module looks like this:**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-common'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'main/'
    test.kotlin.srcDirs += 'test/'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.kotlin
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

**The rootProject `build.gradle`  in Android Studio is:**

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
        anko_version = '0.10.4'
        dagger_version = '2.15'
        support_lib_version = '27.1.1'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the `settings.gradle` file for Android project B

```
def projectA_path = "path/to/projectA"

include(":common")
project(":common").projectDir = new File("$projectA_path/common")

include(":platforms:android")
project(":platforms:android").projectDir = new File("$projectA_path/platforms/android")
```

Even the two are from different projects, according to the setup here. Shouldn't the two just work? What am I missing here?

**IDE version:**

- IDEA Ultimate 2018.1
- Android studio 3.1.2

Comment: Should be an IDE bug, AFAIK

Comment: Can you share a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'
```